# Relative Layout child taking full height of screen

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, android-relativelayout

I am trying to get a chart and 3 buttons in an activity. The 3 buttons should align below the chart. I have the following XML but the buttons are just suppressed by the chart (EDIT for clarity: The buttons are not visible.)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".PlotActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one_week_preset_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/one_week_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one_month_preset_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/one_month_label" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/download_new_data_and_update_graph"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/download_and_update_label" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am pretty sure this can be done easily by two level nesting of linear layouts, but what is the problem with this XML and how to fix this. Any help appreciated.

The above XML produces the following screen as shown in android studio (note that chart occupies the whole screen and hence buttons are not visible)

[image: Chart Occupying complete screen]

Comment: what's the use of linechart, did you also try to use another view inplace of it, pls check with another view like Edittext or View, to ensure, what's the problem which we have to fix, thanks

Comment: @Androider Line chart is used to display a chart(graph). It is from `mpandroidchart` library for plotting graphs. The problem is that the buttons are not showing up in the layout as you can see in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the chart vie as this. It is because you are telling the layout to align parent top and wrap_content which could be to the bottom of the parent . you should tell it that from bottom where is should be.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".PlotActivity">

<com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
    android:id="@+id/chart"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/one_week_preset_button"
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/one_week_preset_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="@string/one_week_label" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/one_month_preset_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/one_month_label" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/download_new_data_and_update_graph"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/download_and_update_label" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I got an exception saying that `circular dependencies cannot exist in relativelayout`